# When to use bundles in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundles, asp.net-optimization

In MVC 4 I can use @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")  to called a bundle of CSS files defined BundleConfig file instead of calling the CSS directly.

When should we use bundle instead of calling directly the file?
I understand it clearly when we have various CSS files to simplify the code. But if there is a single CSS file, should we use a bundle or call it directly?

Comment: see my http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification tutorial. Single or multiple files, bundles can increase first hit response time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Combining multiple files is only one of the various interesting features of bundling.

For instance, bundles allow you to apply various **transformations** (e.g. LESS for CSS; Minification; Obfuscation for JS; etc).

Another nice feature is its built in **caching mechanism**. This ensures that clients will only retrieve a specific version of your bundle once. Any change to your bundle will be picked up by the client on the next request.

Bundles can also be used for **run-time swapping** of CSS or JS files. For instance, serving debug version of a JS framework on your development environment, while serving a minified version on your production environment. The switch can be made in your Global.asax.cs using any custom logic you like (e.g. Web.config parameter; compiler conditionals; etc)

Comment: about the transofrmations, like minification, are they applied by default?

Comment: If you call EnableDefaultBundles() on the BundleCollection (e.g. BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles(); ) then it will automatically include all JS and CSS files AND minify them. If you create your own bundles by hand, no transformations are applied by default. 

Btw, if your project includes pre-minified JS files (*.min.js) then the BundleTable will automatically select these when debugging is disabled. You can explicitly enable or disable this feature with the BundleTable.EnableOptimizations property.